# Javascript keyDown - no event approach

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I'm making game in JavaScript. I have canvas for drawings and game loop. I'd like to make method readKeyboard, in game loop, to check if there is any pressed key. I don't want to attach event to canvas, because it doesn't fit game loop design. Maybe I should attach this event? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a library like [KeyboardJS](http://robertwhurst.github.com/KeyboardJS/), which will listen the keyboard events and fill an array with the active keys.

In your gameloop:

```
var activeKeys = KeyboardJS.activeKeys();
if (activeKeys.indexOf(84) > -1) {
  // key pressed
}
```

I also made [my own library](https://gist.github.com/4069270), which is lighter but clearly less complete than KeyboardJS.