# Receiving keyboard events on a canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas, keyboard, jquery

I need to receive keyboard events in a canvas element. Click events are received but key presses aren't.

Here is my code which doesn't handle key events:

```
var canvasElm = $('canvas');
Event.observe('canvas', 'keypress', function(e) {
    console.log('Key event is received!!');
    console.log(e);
});
```

How can I make it handle those key events?

Comment: [Dupe](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43809/javascript-keydown-no-event-approach), or at least helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the canvas never has the keyboard focus. Keyboard events will be sent to the Window object.

Try adding the events to the Window object. (NB: It might be clearer what's happening if you don't use JQuery)

Comment: +1 For "don't use jQuery" ;) And for finding the solution, of course!

Answer (score 4):

I'm really sorry. I found the solution after ask the question by trying. As MarkR said, we need give focus on our canvas. Here is the pure javascript (without JQuery);

```
canvasElm.setAttribute('tabindex','0');
canvasElm.focus();
```